# hcitool scan output inconsistencies

Tags: bluetooth

When running `hcitool scan`, I get inconsistent output.

Sometimes it finds all nearby, discoverable devices, sometimes it doesn't. The inconsistencies are not because the devices are moving in and out of range. I know this because the devices are my laptop and iPhone, both in discoverable mode.

Even when the devices don't show up in `hcitool scan`, I can still do `hcitool info <DEVICE_ADDR>` and get the information about the device (my iPhone, for example), so I know the device is in range.

Does anyone know why `hcitool scan` isn't showing all actually discoverable devices consistently?

I want to be able to continuously run `hcitool scan` in the background to check for nearby devices.

I'm running ubuntu trusty.

Thanks in advance, and happy to provide more info that'll help.

(EDIT #1)

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb` is:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:9010]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2a Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b0e:0412 GN Netcom 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: What is your BT adapter? Do you use Wi-Fi at the same time?

Comment: is this what you're referring to (re: BT adapter) `[    2.103445] Bluetooth: hci0: read Intel version: 370810011003110e04` ... I ran `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth` (the adapter is built-in) ... and yes Wi-Fi is running on the device as well

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`. I think I know how to fix it.

Comment: Hey @Pilot6, still struggling with this =/, any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off bluetooth coexistence. Run in terminal:

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-opt.conf <<< "options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=N"
```

Reboot after it is done.